# Couldn't create vertex buffer

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I use the lighningchart library and have a problem 'Couldn't create vertex buffer', if the chart is working during 10-20 minutes with realtime updates by websocket, I attached [the image with details of the error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI3jk.png). I can't really understand why this error occurs, so need your help. If you need some more details let me know, please.

Comment: Some immediate pointers;
have you enabled data cleaning? For example, see "setDataCleaning" in  https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/edit/lcjs-example-0028-multiChannelLineProgressiveOwnAxes.html
If this isn't the problem, then will need to see some code.

Comment: @NiiloKeinänen yeah it has been enabled; [look at my config of line series](https://ibb.co/JF9Hs40)

Comment: Can you confirm data being cleaned (disappearing if you look back) during the application run time? The error "couldn't create vertex buffer" hints that WebGL resources have run out. To me it tells that either you have really low resource availability (for example using embedded device etc.) or there is a memory leak in the application or library. For the latter I would need to know how you are using the library (share code).

Comment: @NiiloKeinänen I checked old data from the chart and yeah it's being cleaned. So you need the whole code about the chart from the application, don't you?

Comment: Share what you can - I don't know what is the best. The intention is to let us try and identify any possible problems with how the library methods are used and what the application does.

Comment: @NiiloKeinänen [here is the code of the chart component](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/506407b845a136051e0637fe0b971e8620221130141815/bed8e7) we are using at an application

Comment: I don't see anything smelly in the code. Could you give some pointers on how much data you are supplying into the series during this 10-20 minutes? And what browser vendor and version you encounter the problem in?

Comment: @NiiloKeinänen sure. During 20 minutes it can be near 30_000 points in the summary of 5 variables on the chart. And it can be from 1 to 6 chart instances on the page at the same time. So the maximal amount of points is 180_000 points on the page at the same time.

Browsers where this issue appeared:
Chrome Version 107.0.5304.110 (Official Build) (x86_64)
Chrome Version 108.0.5359.72 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Microsoft EdgeVersion 107.0.1418.62 (Official build) (64-bit)

Comment: Data amount wise this shouldn't be anything problematic. I also tested some long running applications locally and had no problems. I have some more ideas to test when I find the time though... Unless I find something, the next best thing to help resolve the issue would be a minimal application that reproduces the issue. For example, a Code pen that crashes after 30 mins...

Comment: I'm still unable to reproduce the issue. If this is a commercial case, and you would like to proceed, please leave a general inquiry in our website and we can communicate better. https://lightningchart.com/contact/